# Can someone explain to me why pyautogui TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable NoneType object

Tags: python

I'm trying to create a bot that recognizes an image on screen and to be able to click on that image. However, when prompting the bot to click on the image, I am prompted with TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable NoneType object.

```
import pyautogui as pg
import keyboard
import time
import pytesseract as tess
from PIL import Image

if pg.locateOnScreen('follow1.png', confidence=0.5) != None:
    pg.click('follow1.png')
```

However, the bot can recognize the image on screen but fails to click on it.

```
import pyautogui as pg
import keyboard
import time
import pytesseract as tess
from PIL import Image

if pg.locateOnScreen('follow1.png', confidence=0.5) != None:
    pg.print('found it!')
```

How can the script recognize the image on screen but fail to click on it?

Comment: `pg.click('follow1.png')` doesn't follow any of the documented uses of that function. `locateOnScreen` returns a set of coordinates, and `click()` takes coordinates as input; you're not using the returned value of `locateOnScreen` and you're passing a string to `click()`, which I would expect to fail since that's not how that library is documented to work at all. Try reading the documentation for those two functions, look for some examples of their use, and then try again and see if you still have issues.

Comment: This isn't true - pg.click('image.png') is a documented use although it may be erroneous (https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

Comment: As @RandomDavis mentioned, you're better off using locateOnScreen followed by click. locateOnScreen also allows you to specify confidence.

Comment: @Konrads my mistake, I didn't see that use on their official page for `click()`, it must be pretty new?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue, too. I finally found out the reason was that the icon on the screen has changed due to software update. So I used a new snapshot to repalce the old one. And it worked!

```
pyautogui.click('D:/pp/video/3/edit.png')
```

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "", line 1, in 
> File "D:\Users\cordiero\PycharmProjects\untitled\video\lib\site-packages\pyautogui_*init*_.py", line 598, in wrapper
> returnVal = wrappedFunction(*args, **kwargs)
> File "D:\Users\cordiero\PycharmProjects\untitled\video\lib\site-packages\pyautogui_*init*_.py", line 980, in click
> x, y = _normalizeXYArgs(x, y)
> TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable NoneType object
> pyautogui.click('D:/pp/video/3/edit.png')

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty new, so this might not work, but what I did was change this in the code:

From: pyautogui.click('Image.png')

To: pyautogui.click(pyautogui.locateOnScreen('Image.png'))

And it worked for me, hope it also does for you!